# Share microphone within browsers with HTML5

Tags: html, webrtc, html5-audio

I'd like to know how can we share the voice from 2 (or more) different users within a browser without plugins. So, basically, doing a voice conference. Is it already possible? What's the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [getUserMedia API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) to capture Audio & Video from browsers without any plugin. And [PeerConnection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection) to share captured audio with Remote Users.

Start WebRTC [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web) and [see resources](https://webrtc.org/start/).

Once you are comfortable in 1to1 calling,
then read [this](https://webrtchacks.com/web-audio-conference/) for conference in browser.
Or look at WebRTC Servers like Janus/Jitsi/Kurento/FreeSwitch etc for even advanced use cases.